# Specializing a template on functions with different signatures?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template that requires that I pass it a functor as a type parameter in order to perform some calculations.  I would like to specialize this functor based on another function that I want to use to actually perform the calculations.  Basically, I want to do this (which is not legal, I'm redefining the functor):

```
template<typename T, int (*func)(int)>
struct Functor
{
    T val;
    int operator()(int x) { return func(2); }
};

template<typename T, int (*func)(int, int)>
struct Functor 
{
    T val;
    int operator()(int y) { return func(y, 2); }
};

Component<Functor<calculationFunction1>> comp1;
Component<Functor<calculationFunction2>> comp2;

auto result1 = comp1.Compute();
auto result2 = comp2.Compute();
```

I've tried using partial specialization to get this to work as well, but that doesn't seem to be legal, either.  I'm not sure if it's possible to get what I want, since the two functions have differing signatures.  What's the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: Have you considered something like `boost::bind`?

Comment: @JoeZ I looked into it, but I ended up in basically the same place.  The type of the resulting object from using boost::bind on `calculationFunction1` differs from the type of resulting object from `calculationFunction2`.  The `Functor` adapter still needs to be able to handle two different non-type parameters.  Unless I've missed something?

Comment: I guess it really depends on what you're _actually_ doing with the extra arguments in a multi-arg function.  Perhaps an easier question:  Why do you need to specialize `Functor` directly?  Why can't you have a `Functor1` and a `Functor2` to handle single-arg and dual-arg functions?

Comment: @JoeZ Initially, for ease of use.  There are a few of these functions and I wanted to present the other users of these component a single adapter to use to wrap whatever function they needed to pass to Component.  I haven't been able to find a better solution, so I think I will have to use two `Functor`s as you suggest.

Comment: It seems like in principle it should be possible.  After all, `boost::bind` works and can work with functions with varying numbers of arguments.  I guess with `bind`, you know the number of arguments in the bound function from the number of arguments to `bind` itself.  I guess I need to bone up on my template metaprogramming wizardry.

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
template<typename T, typename SOME_FUNC_TYPE, SOME_FUNC_TYPE func >
struct Functor {};

typedef int (*SingleArgFunc)(int);
typedef int (*DoubleArgFunc)(int,int);

template<typename T, SingleArgFunc func>
struct Functor<T, SingleArgFunc, func>
{
  T val;
  int operator()(int x) { return func(2); }
};

template<typename T, DoubleArgFunc func>
struct Functor<T, DoubleArgFunc, func>
{
  T val;
  int operator()(int y) { return func(y, 2); }
};

int calculationFunction1 (int) { return 0; }
int calculationFunction2 (int, int) { return 0; }

template <typename FUNCTOR>
struct Component
{
  int Compute (void) { return FUNCTOR()(0); }
};

Component<Functor<int, decltype(&calculationFunction1), calculationFunction1>> comp1;
Component<Functor<int, decltype(&calculationFunction2), calculationFunction2>> comp2;

auto result1 = comp1.Compute();
auto result2 = comp2.Compute();
```